# Multiple simultaneous calls to POST method resulting in overriding

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, post, get

In my website, I have added buttons which upon click sent an ajax POST method using fetch API. When the same async function which has the ajax call is called simultaneouly (or within short intervals), it adds items to cart. The front end shows that the promise was fulfilled. But when I refresh the page and use the GET method to get the items added, it shows less items than before. For example, if I have 0 items in cart and spam click the button 6 times. It shows that 6 items are added to cart. But when I refresh, it sometimes shows less than 6.
Here is somewhat similar code. The below code does not override the other requests as everything is happening in the front end itself (I think).

```js
var num = 0
var itemCounter = 0
var successCounter = 0

const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')

wrapper.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    itemCounter++
    addToCart(itemCounter)
  }
})

async function addToCart(itemId) {
  try {
    // Insert ajax POST method here using fetch API instead of the below
    const myFetch = new Promise((resolve) => {
      const duration = 1000 * Math.ceil(3 * Math.random())
      setTimeout(() => {
        successCounter++
        num += 1
        resolve(`Item: ${itemId} added to cart. Items in cart: ${num}`)
      }, duration)
    })
    const response = await myFetch
    console.log(response)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}

const statusBtn = document.querySelector('.get-status')

statusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('-------------------------')
  console.log(`Items: ${successCounter}`)
  console.log('-------------------------')
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
</div>

<button class="get-status">Get Status</button>
```

To get over this, I created a queue of requests and the handled them one by one like the following.

```js
var num = 0
var itemCounter = 0
var successCounter = 0

const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')

wrapper.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    itemCounter++
    taskQueue.push(itemCounter)
    if (isExecuting) {
        printSqrt('Btn clikced')
      return
    }
    isExecuting = true
    executeQueue()
  }
})

const taskQueue = []
var isExecuting = false
async function executeQueue() {
  while (taskQueue.length != 0) {
    const item = taskQueue.shift()
    await addToCart(item)
  }
  printSqrt('In queue')
  isExecuting = false
}

async function addToCart(itemId) {
  try {
    const myFetch = new Promise((resolve) => {
      const duration = 1000 * Math.ceil(3 * Math.random())
      setTimeout(() => {
        successCounter++
        num += 1
        resolve(`Item: ${itemId} added to cart. Items in cart: ${num}`)
      }, duration)
    })
    const response = await myFetch
    console.log(response)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}

function printSqrt(calledFrom) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var z = Math.sqrt(i)
    console.log(calledFrom + ' ' + z)
  }
}

const statusBtn = document.querySelector('.get-status')

statusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('-------------------------')
  console.log(`Items requested: ${itemCounter}`)
  console.log(`Items added: ${successCounter}`)
  console.log('-------------------------')
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
</div>

<button class="get-status">Get Status</button>
```

This solved the problem. But the thing I am unsure of now is that since simultaneous calls are made to the same async function, what their order of execution is. Since javascript is single threaded, is the execution of one async function stopped to run another async function (in this case, it's the same function)? This will matter when setting the `isExecuting` boolean. So when the for loop prints squareroots, I can click the button to call `executeQueue` again. There is a possibility that when the `executeQueue` was printing square roots, `isExecuting` is still true (but it has exited the while loop) and while this is happening, I click the Click Me button. But it doesn't execute the queue and returns because it sees `isExecuting` is true. So the queue has now one element which is not added to the cart and it will remain there till the button is clicked again. This is again a problem of shared resources between synchronous and asynchronous functions.

Comment: you should not need the boolean if you implement promises correctly. Have a search for async queue since it has been implemented thousands of times

Comment: @mplungjan In my actual code in the website, I am using `await fetch()` instead of `await new Promise()`. If there is significant time gap between clicking the buttons, the data gets updated correctly in the server. But if I spam the buttons, the promises are resolved but there is data missing in the backend.